# Gmail smtp server broken security settings

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, google-apps

i'm trying to send email via google apps acc, using smtp server using c#, but i get error "Gmail Error :The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required". Now, most of the answers to this question are outdated and wrong, so let's unravel this mysterious detective. The truth that is up to date :
1) "lesssecureapps" settings are not available for google apps acc.
2) password is correct, login is correct.
3) people in google forums are lost themselves, they dont know anything about their product, its like talking to a dealer, that was caught be the cops - "i dont know anything", so no answers "ask in google forums".
4) in account activity, i see lots of "Account disabled", "Account enabled".

Comment: Just wanted to add, i need a way to force google to accept my security settings and let me send emails, once and for all....

Comment: is this in your local system or in server?

Comment: In server, and server is added to google apps account devices list.

Comment: is the server in different timestamp?? do u have remote access to server..if so just login and singin to gmail from any browser once

Comment: Short history : first, google failed to send emails, i had to change a setting in admin account, that controls my google apps account, then it sends emails for like a month, then emails sending stoped again, had to add server to google apps acc devices, then it was working for a few weeks, and now it is broken again, and i cant find anything, also all google help and forums are useless.

Comment: try this link from server https://g.co/allowaccess

Comment: is it working..any luck?

Comment: Yes, that link worked, but google services are really bad, will have to move far away from google in the future.

Comment: glad to hear it worked

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Apps SMTP Relay Service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en) can be configured to accept unencrypted and without username/password authentication. This would be the proper way to configure an internal server or application to send out mail from your domain and Google Apps.